# How to create Two Level JSON

Tags: json

How to create Two Level JSON, if i have to get data in multiple lists, like below:

```
  Category's List > Item's List
```

**For an example**: Sony > LED TV, Laptop, Phones etc..

Earlier i have created single Level JSON,

**For an example:** LED TV, Laptop, Phones see below:

```
[
    {
        "ProductID":"1",
        "ProductName":"LED TV"
    },
    {
        "ProductID":"2",
        "ProductName":"Laptop"
    }
]
```

So here my question is how my JSON should look like ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any JSON "data type" as values. So here, you would create an object whose keys are the categories and the values are arrays of products:

```
{
    "Sony": [{
        "ProductID": "1",
        "ProductName": "LED TV"
    }, {
        ...
    }],
    "Panasonic": [...]
}
```

Instead of using an array of products, you could also use an object of object, keyed by produce ID. Optimize the structure for your use case, i.e. structure it in such a way that you can easily access the information you need.

See http://json.org/ for a complete syntax description.

Comment: It's as simple as `{"category": {"product_id": {...}}}`.

Comment: by using this {"category": {"product_id": {...}}}   you mean in place of "category" i should use Sony, Panasonic, Samsung and so on. am i right?

Comment: hmmm... @FelixKling i think KLAmitSuri is right, still have some doubts in my mind regarding as an object of object, i guess sample JSON will help us to know it in a better way...

Comment: @Sonali: What exactly is the problem? JSON is a very simple data format. At top level you typically have an array or object, i.e. `[value, value,...]` or `{"key": value, "key": value}`. Valid values are strings (`"foo"`), numbers (`42`), `null`, `true`, `false` and also arrays (`[...]`) and objects (`{...}`). This makes it possible to nest arrays and objects, but whether they are nested or not doesn't make a difference, the syntax is always the same.

Answer (score 1):

yeah I agree with @FelixKling in one of my app i have used same kind of JSON:

```
{
 "Mixed Platter" : [
    {
        "title" : "Veggie",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse adipiscing elit.",
        "cost" : "5.25"
    },
    {
        "title" : "Non Veggie",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse adipiscing elit.",
        "cost" : "5.75"
    }
    ],
    "Soups" : [
    {
        "title" : "Mulagatawny Soup",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse adipiscing elit.",
        "cost" : "3.75"
    },
    {
        "title" : "Daal Soup",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse adipiscing elit.",
        "cost" : "3.25"
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: i am also looking for code to fetch data into ListView in Android, will you help me?

Comment: try using this code to get data into multiLevel List: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-multilevel-listview-tutorial/

Comment: not done with above code, if possible so please send me a demo code here: sonali.kohlimca@gmail.com

Comment: @SonaliKohli sorry to say, but try at your end, if problem comes, come back here and ask a question, will definitely help you

Answer (score -1):

```
[
    {
        "author": "anonymous",
        "background": "0xaaaaaa",
        "ball": "0xff1111",
        "mat": "0xffff00",
        "bouncer": "0xff00ff",
        "obstacle": "0x00ddff",
        "data":
        [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
        ]
    }
]
```